# How to get retrieve Captcha Image from Captcha Image String android?

Tags: android, string, image, captcha

I am doing a webservice based app in android. I need to use Captcha Image in Register Page.
I get Captcha Image in String Format by webservice. Now I don't know how to parse that string to get the corresponding captcha image? I have no any idea about this?

Comment: Give more information. Such as which captcha engine is being used in the webserver. There is NO universal captcha. Did you not get any API doc for the webservice your are using? And, if you cant answer these, at least include the 'String response' you are getting from server in your question.

Comment: It's very hard to understand what you're asking for exactly. So, your Android application sends a request to your web service, which then returns an image (in String format?). If this is the actual image, then I guess you could read that image as a byte array and then convert it into a Bitmap - then you could use that Bitmap to display it in an ImageView or whatever..

Comment: Take a look at `BitmapFactory`: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/BitmapFactory.html It can create bitmaps from byte arrays and streams, among other things. Once you have `Bitmap` object with captcha, you can display it in `ImageView`.